# DB record versioning

Tags: mysql, database

I have following task: There is DB which contains all the data. We have some scrappers which update DB with newest data from some resources(external sites/systems) and we need to implement following logic: one type of users should see latest data but another type of users should see data which was in DB 15 minutes ago. So my initial solutions was to have 2 DB and sync them each 15 minutes but are there any other solutions to implement that?

Thanks,

Comment: Store both , and a timestamp

Comment: what do you mean by storing both? both versions of data in one DB? like newest version and 15 mins before version?

Comment: Yes. Exactamente.

Answer (score 1):

When you have another server available, you can set up replication with a delay of 15 minutes. Then you send the up-to-date-users to server 1 and the 15-minutes-later-users to server 2.

Read more about it here: [Delayed Replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-delayed.html)

You can even set up replication on the same server, but that's a bit tricky. The amount of data doubles of course.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I had similar thought on how to handle that. I heard another opinion that RDBS have some version control for each row and I can use it... But I'm not sure if it's possible.

Comment: In my opinion that's too much of a hastle. With replication you have a clean solution and near to no work :)